# How does activating ActRaiser 2's "Difficulty 202" mode work?

Tags: actraiser-2

ActRaiser 2 (SNES, 1993) has a password system for saving one's progress and easy, normal, and hard modes. But PJ, a notable streamer and speedrunner of ActRaiser 2, published [a speedrun](http://www.speedrun.com/run/9yor6xjy) of the game in an unfamiliar "Difficulty 202", accessed by entering a special password. According to [the description of this run of one level](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YjMiBXGujN0), "nearly every enemy in the game kills me upon contact and has too much health to kill in any realistic amount of time".

How does this work within the game? Was this password written deliberately or is it a bug that somehow works perfectly?

Answer (score 1):

People typically consider this mode a glitched mode and is considered an "Impossible" mode for ActRaiser 2. I don't know that the creators have given an answer on how deliberate the mode is, but it can be accessed with the password:

```
SWZX LKCF XHLW
```

I found more information on a board from GameFAQs:

> There are actually two different glitch modes for this game, Extreme
>   Mode is beatable, but Impossible Mode is impossible. I will explain
>   them both.
>
> Extreme Mode: Same steps as outlined, but the difficulty is set to
>   "Normal"
>
> Impossible Mode: Same steps, but you must set the difficulty to "Hard"
>
> 1. After completing Death Heim with the 38 lives password (or simply by inputting any Extreme Mode password and then resetting the game),
>      then skip the demo and go to the title screen and change the
>      difficulty from Normal to Hard. After selecting Hard difficulty,
>      simply reset the game. Make sure you do NOT start the game after
>      selecting the difficulty. Simply select it and reset. There will be a
>      demo sequence where the Master dies in midair due to time running out.
>      Then the game advances into the "Impossible Mode"
>
> In Impossible Mode, you get 50 lives to start. The timer starts at 99,
>   but goes down extremely fast. It goes down about 10 "game seconds" for
>   every 1 second of real life. Also, the enemies in Extreme Mode that
>   kill you instantly will do no damage, and the ones that did no damage
>   will kill you instantly. The roles appear to have switched. You will
>   die after approximately 10 seconds, making every level seemingly
>   impossible to complete. Otherwise, Impossible Mode is exactly like
>   Extreme Mode, insane amounts of HP and whatnot for different enemies.
>
> No level (as far as I know) is doable in this mode. However, the
>   password for this mode is simply...
>
> SWZX LKCF XZPF
>
> This starts you off at the beginning

[Source](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/563503-actraiser-2/61566043)

Comment: I was asking more about how it works on a technical level. But thanks for finding that source.